# What's the difference between Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?

Tags: pi-3

Have a number of questions but let me start with this one: Is the Pi3 Model B an improved/faster version of Pi 3? I'm looking at Pi3s for sale on walmart.com from a few vendors (Viaboot, ZiggyMemory, VILROS) and see different options in their kits. One includes heatsinks, another a fan, if heat is an issue which of these options is better? One vendor (EEEKit) only sells kits and not Pi3. Looking at their kit wonder what the advantage is because it's got open sides, maybe for heat dispersion (https://www.walmart.com/ip/EEEKit-for-Raspberry-Pi-3-Model-B-Sliced-9-Layers-Case-Box-Cooling-Fan-SanDisk-16GB-Memory-Card-HDMI-Cable/113846451)? Anyway, have learned from research that Pi 3 is a 1GB motherboard, thought I saw 2GB somewhere, but did read that swapping can emulate more RAM. Here's some more Walmart links, if anyone has some recommendations (that I won't hold you responsible for) for best of these to purchase, please advise me. These all have the closed case and purchasing from Walmart just because have a gift card from there (will include descriptions vs links):
Low price, heatsinks, but no HDMI cable
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Basic Starter Kit--Black Case Edition

This case kit (no motherboard) is $10.97. Would go well with motherboard and power supply only
EEEKit 3in1 Kit for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B,Transparent 6-layer Case Box w/ Cooling Fan+Aluminum Heatsink+HDMI Cable

Anyway, appreciate any suggestions on all of the above.

Comment: Shopping suggestions are off-topic.  There is only one Pi3, that is the Pi3B.  See https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/

Comment: They are one and the same.

Answer (score 7):

There have been and still are several RPi models, including:

- The A series, a (then) small form-factor board.
- The B series with multiple USB ports and on-board wired Ethernet.
- The Zero series in a low-cost, small form-factor.

Within each of these models, there have been upgrades. For example, the B model has been released over the years as:

- The original B, with 512M RAM, a single-core CPU, Ethernet and 2 USB ports.
- The B+ with 512M RAM, a single-core CPU, Ethernet and 4 USB ports.
- The 2B with 1G RAM, a quad-core CPU, Ethernet and 4 USB ports.
- The 3B with 1G RAM, a quad-core CPU, Ethernet, bluetooth and wifi and 4 USB ports.

The "3" model is the 3B. There have been no other numbered variants of other models.

Comment: The original B actually had 256MB of RAM and was later replaced by an identical B v2 with 512MB of RAM

Comment: Now there is a 3A+ https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-product-raspberry-pi-3-model-a/

Answer (score 3):

There has been only one Raspberry Pi 3. That is the Rasperry Pi 3 Model B. As of September 2017 the Raspberry Pi 3 Model A doesn't exist.

Comment: Now there is not only a 3B+ but also a 3A+.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, first ask what you need this pi to do? If it is cpu intensive then get the heatsink and fan otherwise just get the pi, you don't need frills.

Comment: This doesn't answer the full question. It only references the part of the question regarding heat sinks and totally ignores the aspect about model numbers.